# Bootstrap to OpenStack cloud asks password to log in

Tags: ssh, juju

I'm testing the new beta OpenStack cloud of CloudVPS.com and hitting a few problems.

The first problem (which I assume is very likely CloudVPS beta related) is that about half of the time the bootstrapped server is assigned IP's (three, is this normal?) - but they are not reachable, so the bootstrap fails after 10 minutes. Checked that the IP's are really not reachable, so something on the network level fails. This problem can likely be ignored here (raising with their support).

The other problem is that when the server can be reached, the bootstrap asks for a password - and failing to give that (would not know what to give), fails the bootstrap.

```
$ juju bootstrap --show-log --debug
2013-12-31 17:48:18 DEBUG juju.environs.configstore disk.go:77 Making /home/jaywink/.juju/environments
2013-12-31 17:48:18 INFO juju.provider.openstack provider.go:156 opening environment "cloudvps"
2013-12-31 17:48:20 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:46 bootstrapping environment "cloudvps"
2013-12-31 17:48:21 DEBUG juju.environs.bootstrap synctools.go:91 looking for bootstrap tools: series="precise", arch=<nil>, version=<nil>
2013-12-31 17:48:21 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.17
2013-12-31 17:48:21 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-12-31 17:48:21 DEBUG juju.environs.tools tools.go:44 no architecture specified when finding tools, looking for any
2013-12-31 17:48:21 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:667 using default candidate for content id "com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools" are {20131025 mirrors:1.0 content-download streams/v1/cpc-mirrors.sjson []}
2013-12-31 17:48:22 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:538 no mirror information available for {NL https://identity.stack.cloudvps.com/v2.0}: mirror info with cloud {NL https://identity.stack.cloudvps.com/v2.0} not found
2013-12-31 17:48:22 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:462 read metadata index at "https://streams.canonical.com/tools/streams/v1/index.sjson"
2013-12-31 17:48:22 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:625 candidate matches for products ["com.ubuntu.juju:12.04:amd64" "com.ubuntu.juju:12.04:i386" "com.ubuntu.juju:12.04:arm"] are [{Sat, 26 Oct 2013 00:56:32 +1000 products:1.0 content-download  [] streams/v1/com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools.sjson [com.ubuntu.juju:12.04:amd64 com.ubuntu.juju:13.10:amd64]}]
2013-12-31 17:48:22 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:937 finding products at path "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools.sjson"
2013-12-31 17:48:22 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:974 metadata: &{map[com.ubuntu.juju:12.04:amd64:{ 1.17.0 amd64   map[20131026:0xc200533360]} com.ubuntu.juju:13.10:amd64:{ 1.17.0 amd64   map[20131026:0xc200533480]}] map[] Sat, 26 Oct 2013 00:56:32 +1000 products:1.0 }
2013-12-31 17:48:22 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:58 picked newest version: 1.17.0
Launching instance
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:481 fetchData failed for "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/index.sjson": cannot find URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/index.sjson" not found
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:458 cannot load index "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/index.sjson": invalid URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/index.sjson" not found
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:481 fetchData failed for "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/mirrors.json": cannot find URL "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/mirrors.json" not found
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:557 no mirror index file found
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:462 read metadata index at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/streams/v1/index.json"
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:625 candidate matches for products ["com.ubuntu.cloud:server:12.04:amd64"] are [{Sun, 29 Dec 2013 22:52:21 +0200 products:1.0 image-ids custom [{NL https://identity.stack.cloudvps.com/v2.0}] streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud:released:imagemetadata.json [com.ubuntu.cloud:server:12.04:amd64]}]
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:937 finding products at path "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud:released:imagemetadata.json"
2013-12-31 17:48:23 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:974 metadata: &{map[com.ubuntu.cloud:server:12.04:amd64:{ 12.04 amd64   map[20132912:0xc200492a20]}] map[] Sun, 29 Dec 2013 22:52:21 +0200 products:1.0 com.ubuntu.cloud:custom}
2013-12-31 17:48:24 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:705 openstack user data; 525 bytes
2013-12-31 17:48:27 INFO juju.provider.openstack provider.go:752 started instance "f259497c-5c4f-49c1-980b-d74d73159f83"
 - f259497c-5c4f-49c1-980b-d74d73159f83
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 213.187.240.25:22
Attempting to connect to 185.21.189.219:22
Attempting to connect to 185.21.188.115:22
ubuntu@185.21.189.219's password: 2013-12-31 17:58:28 ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:85 bootstrap failed: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect
Stopping instance...
2013-12-31 17:58:28 DEBUG juju.provider.openstack provider.go:775 terminating instances [f259497c-5c4f-49c1-980b-d74d73159f83]
2013-12-31 17:58:29 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:294 waited for 10m0s without being able to connect
```

During the 10 minutes I can verify that the machine is in fact running ok from their user interface. For some reason it just isn't logging in with the SSH key that I assume is uploaded during the machine creation.

Any ideas how to debug this? Running Juju 1.17.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were related to the CloudVPS Compute beta, should be fixed when the platform goes public.

Answer (score 1):

Juju 1.17.0 has a new bootstrap mechanism, which may be to blame here. There's a few possible answers I can think of:

1. There's a problem with your SSH keys. This seems unlikely, but the way bootstrap works now is that your public keys will be added to the newly started machine's ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys. Thus, logging in *should* not require a password.
2. The cloud-init script isn't initialising authorized_keys properly. Also seems unlikely.
3. The IP address is routable, but not for the correct machine.

In the log you've provided, there are three IPs: which is the public one according to CloudVPS? While trying to bootstrap, you could try, in parallel, to ssh to each of the IPs as the `ubuntu` user (ssh ubuntu@ip). If none of them works, then I'd suggest logging a bug against Juju; if one of them works, then I think that would suggest point 3 above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Been a really weird and fruitless debugging experience - and I'm not sure which problems are due to CloudVPS in beta and which due to Juju.
In 1.6.5 at least the bootstrap doesn't decimate the server if it cannot connect to it so trying with that. Answers: 1) The key is fine, though password protected - assume that is not a problem as I unlock it on boot? 2) I wish I could log in via console in web UI but 'ubuntu' user I guess has no password. 3) CloudVPS have not answered network issue query yet.

Comment: Also this problem is something that only happens sometimes. Right now I cannot reproduce it since I cannot get a bootstrap where the machines are even reachable :)